# Repository always null after starting the application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to develop an application in java where you can log in your credentials in frontend with JavaFX and it will log you in automatically with chrome web driver. For storage of password and email I use H2-Database with Spring Framework.

Unfortunately if I start the application the repository is always null. The Nullpointer Exception comes, when I try to access the repository. In other questions the reason has always been the dependeny injection. I tried all three Dependeny Injections (constructor level, setter level, field level). Here is my code:

MBA (website, where I want to login):

```
@Entity
@Getter
public class MBA {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    
    public static WebDriver driver;
    private static int amountOfSales;
    
    public MBA() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.email = null;
        this.password = null;
    }
    
    public MBA(String email, String password) {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

**MBAApplicationService:**

```
@Service
public class MBAApplicationService {

    public static WebDriver driver;
    private static int amountOfSales;
    
    private MBARepository mbaRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public MBAApplicationService(MBARepository mbaRepository) {
        this.mbaRepository = mbaRepository;
    }
    
    public void saveLogin(String email, String password) {
        MBA mba = new MBA(email, password);
        mbaRepository.save(mba);
    }
    
    public void chromeDriverSetUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

}
```

**MBARepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface MBARepository extends CrudRepository\<MBA, UUID\> {

}
```

**Controller (Controller of JavaFXApplication):**

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class Controller {

    //Integrationtest
    
    @FXML private Label mainSceneLabel;
    @FXML private Label loginsSceneLabel;
    @FXML private Label sellerSceneLabel;
    @FXML private TextField emailMBA;
    @FXML private PasswordField passwordMBA;
    @FXML private Label mbaAmountOfSales;
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;
    
    @Autowired
    private MBARepository mbaRepository;
    
    @FXML
    public void openLoginScene() throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("LoginsScene.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)(mainSceneLabel.getScene().getWindow());
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void openMainScene() throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("1_MainScene.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)(loginsSceneLabel.getScene().getWindow());
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    @FXML
    public void switchToSellerViewScene() throws IOException {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SellerViewScene.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)(mainSceneLabel.getScene().getWindow());
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    
    public void saveLogins() {
        //Amazon
        String emailAmazon = emailMBA.getText();
        String passwordAmazon = passwordMBA.getText();
        MBAApplicationService mbaApplicationService = new MBAApplicationService(mbaRepository);
        mbaApplicationService.saveLogin(emailAmazon, passwordAmazon);
    }

}
```

**Here is the error notification I get, when I want to save something in the repository:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "mba.MBARepository.save(Object)" because "this.mbaRepository" is null at com.example.moduleinfo/mba.MBAApplicationService.saveLogin(MBAA>pplicationService.java:58)
    at com.example.moduleinfo/com.example.moduleinfo.Controller.saveLogins(Controller.java:85)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 53 more
```

Here are my configurations:
[Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bemvN.png)

Comment: You create the Service with `new` keyword. That's why autowiering is not working: `MBAApplicationService mbaApplicationService = new MBAApplicationService(mbaRepository);`. Autowire the Service in the controller and it should work

Comment: Where/how do you create the `Controller` instance?

Comment: @Jens I did autowire the Service in the Controller. Now there is a service, which has a mbaRepository as Null Object :(

Comment: Shouldl I put @Controller above Controller Class?

Comment: Yes of course. But it is more or less the same as `@Service`. But if the autowiering is not working, it looks like you have a problem in your configuration. Can you share the configuration?

Comment: @Jens Posted it after the question